# PowerShell: Select-String -Pattern -Unique not working as expected

Tags: regex, powershell

Im hopeless with REGEX and have been stumped on this for a while. Basically im trying scrape a href tag from a html body but the -unique param does not seem to work...

Href example:

`<a href='www.google.com'>War Room</a>`

Here is my code:

```
$warRoomLink = $item.incident_updates.body | Select-String -Pattern '(?i)<a[^>]*>(.*)</a>' -AllMatches | ForEach-Object { $_.matches } | ForEach-Object { $_.value } | Select-Object -Unique
```

Current Output:

```
WarRoom WarRoom WarRoom
```

Desired Output:

```
WarRoom
```

TIA

Comment: Is `$item.incident_updates.body` a string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Correct

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew for example in the body there is a specific ID number that I can regex perfectly fine however it doesn't seem to work properly (receiving multiple values) for the <a> tag

Comment: Try `[regex]::Matches($item.incident_updates.body, '(?is)<a[^>]*>(.*?)</a>') | % { $_.groups[1].value } | Select-Object -Unique`

Comment: sorry @WiktorStribiżew do you mind putting that with the variables above? I don't really understand what it does

Comment: I have tried ```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew wow perfect that actually seems to work! However its not hyperlinked. Any ideas?

Comment: like it doesn't contain the actual href value

Comment: Do you mean you need the whole text? Then use `[regex]::Matches($item.incident_updates.body, '(?is)<a[^>]*>.*?</a>') | % { $_.value } | Select-Object -Unique`

Comment: Correct I do mean the whole text - so your code just brought me back to what I was seeing originally - their is multiple <a> tag values

Comment: Sorry, your current question has become too unclear, with exact sample text + expected outout it is not possible to further help you.

Comment: Why use regex at all? Have a look at [How to Extract Links Off Any Webpage Using PowerShell](https://www.howtogeek.com/124736/stupid-geek-tricks-extract-links-off-any-webpage-using-powershell/)

Comment: If you only want one, try `Select -First 1` instead of `-Unique`?

Answer (score 0):

If you need unique links:

```
(Invoke-WebRequest –Uri 'http://somesite.com').Links | Select-Object -Unique
```

There are more tricks for this task, see [How to Extract Links Off Any Webpage Using PowerShell](https://www.howtogeek.com/124736/stupid-geek-tricks-extract-links-off-any-webpage-using-powershell/).

Answer (score 0):

the suggestion made by @user19702 was the one that worked perfectly for me.

```
Select -First 1
```